# dynamic inheritance in C++

Tags: c++, inheritance

In interview I faced the question about dynamic inheritance, but i had never used the dynamic inheritance in C++.
I want to know how can we implement dynamic inheritance in C++ and what is the practical use of dynamic inheritance in C++ language?

Comment: Google gives several good hits with the subject.

Comment: What's "dynamic inheritance"?

Comment: Which company was that ? Probably interviewer didn't knew what he was talking about or you misunderstood what he was asking.

Comment: @Mahesh: Some interview Questions are seldom trick Questions.

Comment: @Als hmmm ... interviewer is trying to trick interviewee. Bad interviewer IMO, it's difficult to learn and understand existing language features amidst unspecified and undefined behaviors in C++.

Comment: @Mahesh: There is nothing Unspecified or Undefined in this.It just does not exist! It can be done to gauge the confidence or what authority a potential candidate commands over the language.

Comment: I could speculate that he was talking about virtual inheritance... but then, it would be hard to know exactly without the interviewer actually stepping up and clarifying!

Comment: @Als: I was just saying in general, nothing specific to this question. I take what you commented :)

Answer (score 11):

Dynamic inheritance should mean that you can alter the class hierarchy at runtime.

This is something which should be pretty straightforward to do in a dynamic language. For instance, in Javascript, an object will have a `prototype` property. If you try to access a method or property not defined for that object, it will be looked up in the prototype object, and so on. If you change the prototype, you're effectively changing what the object is and can do. See [here](http://www.packtpub.com/article/using-prototype-property-in-javascript) and on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype-based_programming#Delegation) for a more sound description.

As for how you could implement this in C++, it would probably be pretty messy. For a simplified example:

```
class A{

public:

    /*some fields*/

    virtual ~A() { }
    virtual void f() = 0;
    virtual void g() = 0;

};

class B1 : public A{
public:
    virtual void f(){ /*B1 implementation*/ }
    virtual void g(){ /*B1 implementation*/ }
};

class B2 : public A{
public:
    virtual void f(){ /*B2 implementation*/ }
    virtual void g(){ /*B2 implementation*/ }
};

class C : public B1{

public:
    /* ... */

};
```

you should be able to simply (although in a compiler-specific way) switch the `vptr` in a `C` object to point to the v-table for `B2` at runtime, and you'd have your `C` behaving as if its class inherited from `B2`. This approach can get messy really quickly if we bring in object layouts, and possibly automatic inlining - say, if the compiler thinks it knows what the dynamic type of the object is and doesn't bother with the vtable.

To do it properly in C++, my guess is you might need to resort to some sort of table system, perhaps using [metatables](http://phrogz.net/lua/LearningLua_ValuesAndMetatables.html) as in Lua, and then you'd be throwing away all manners of comfortable syntax. Or you'd end up with a scripting language. In a certain sense, since most dynamic language interpreters are written in C or C++, you could argue that they add dynamic inheritance support to C++.

Point is (and this is why the anonymous downvoter kid downvoted my colleagues' answers), even if you're asked a seemingly silly question in an interview, you're supposed to think about possible solutions. The interviewer might have wanted to know how much you know about C++ and/or dynamic languages, or how you'd interpret the term dynamic inheritance and come up with a possibly plausible model for it.

Answer (score 9):

You can't and none. There is no such thing as dynamic inheritance.

You could be referring to `dynamic_cast`, which is a whole other kettle of fish.

Answer (score 7):

There is no such thing.

It's just a string of words, put together in an associative way.